# Setting the Script folder location using a Function fails

Tags: powershell

I have created a function with a piece of code that works fine in a script but fails when it is converted to a function.

The code sets the location where the script resides as current location.

```
Function Set-ScriptFolder
{
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
        Sets the location to the folder where the script folder resides.
        .DESCRIPTION
        Sets the location to the folder where the script folder resides.
        .EXAMPLE
        Set-ScriptFolder
        .EXAMPLE
        Set-ScriptFolder
    #>


    $location = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    set-location $location

}
```

The output is:

```
Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

set-location : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null. Change the value of argument
"path" to a non-null value.
```

Any idea how to convert:

```
   $location = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    set-location $location
```

to a function?

Thanks

Comment: `$MyInvocation` in a function is the invocation information of the function isn't it? That would be the problem I think. Which means you get to pass the argument in to your function from the script I think... but why bother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `$MyInvocation`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) you would see ....

> `$MyInvocation` is populated only for scripts, function, and script blocks. 
>          You can use the information in the System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
>          object that $MyInvocation returns in the current script, such as the path
>          and file name of the script (`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`) **or the name of a
>          function** (`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name`) to identify the current command.

You can see the output of `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` inside your function would return:

```
Set-ScriptFolder
```

**Alternate solutions**

You could use the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$PSScriptRoot` instead.

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
```

That should work inside the function as well. If you prefer you could also use the propery `PSScriptRoot` of `$MyInvocation` as long as you have PowerShell 3.0 or higher.

```
Set-Location $MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot
```

Function for just one line does seem a little overkill.

Comment: Thanks, Set-Location $MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot works but $PSScriptRoot  does not work well.

Comment: @RalJans make sure you're actually saving the file and not running it from ISE in an unsaved file. `$PSScriptRoot` only works when run from a file.